# Error using \usepackage{fancyvrb, fancybox}

Tags: errors, debugging, fancyvrb

With TeX Live 2009, with this MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb, fancybox}  
\begin{document}
    \begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
      auto eth0
    \end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error when compiling

```
Runaway argument?
      auto eth0^^M    \end{Verbatim}^^M^^M\end{document} ! File ended while scanning use of \Verbatim. <inserted text>
```

Using

```
\usepackage{fancybox, fancyvrb}
```

makes the error go away, but it is disturbing. I assume that `fancyvrb` depends on `fancybox`, but the packages don't handle this gracefully. This took me a while to track down. For reference, I was looking at Peter Flynn's example in http://groups.google.com/group/latexusersgroup/browse_thread/thread/c8c2e5dd1e9ff5cf

The message in question starts with

> I don't understand the problem. What I wrote works in any class. Just
>   copy  and paste it into a report.

and his example has those packages loaded in that order, to be precise `\usepackage{fancyvrb,fancybox,calc}`. So my question is, what is going wrong here precisely, and how can I effectively debug these kinds of issues in the future?

UPDATE: The choice between's Enrico's solution and Werner's solution was basically a tossup. I did like Enrico's identification of a problem with the `fancybox` `Verbatim` environment. However, I still am not clear how one can efficiently identify these problems when they crop up. If anyone has debugging tips, I'd like to hear them.

Comment: `\end{Verbatim}` _must_ start in the first column of a line

Comment: @Herbert: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: spaces _before_ `\end{Verbatim}` are not allowed.

Comment: @Herbert: Don't follow. Not allowed according to who/what?

Comment: Debugging starts with patience! `:)` You literally have to pull the code apart by removing things (unnecessary packages, code or commands) in order to find the root of the problem. It's very subjective, since experience plays a big part in where to look and what to look for. For example, since load order played a part here, it definitely made me suspicious that one package might redefine a command. Completely dropping one was sufficient. Then, upon further investigation, I noticed the difference in notation, and experimented with either. Widdling it down to an MWE is always best.

Comment: @Werner: Ok. I thought there might be some tipoff in the error message wrt what the problem was. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: No, LaTeX is notoriously cryptic when it comes to *some* error messages. Since, as a macro language, problems may arise from deep within TeX's "digestive system" where it is really obvious what the problem is... but at the higher level it is sometimes bizarre. That's why most debugging comes with experience. Of course, this is just *my* opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have noticed that in Peter Flynn's message the syntax used is

```
\begin{Verbatim}{frame=single}
```

and not

```
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
```

This makes quite a big difference. Moreover, the `Verbatim` environment as redefined by `fancybox` seems not to like blank spaces in front of `\end{Verbatim}`: the following input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}{frame=single}
   auto eth0
 \end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

raises the

```
Runaway argument?
{frame=single}^^M   auto eth0^^M \end{Verbatim}^^M\end{document}^^M
! File ended while scanning use of \FV@BeginScanning.
```

error.

Of course, both packages trying to redefine `\VerbatimEnvironment` is not very helpful to the user. However, if you load `fancyvrb` as second, you get all of its functionality, without losing `fancybox`'s as regards to boxes and frames. The implementation of the verbatim environments in `fancybox` seems buggy (the requirement that `\end{Verbatim}` starts on column 1 is surely a bug), so I believe it's best to say

```
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyvrb}
```

Comment: Hi egreg. Thanks for the pointers. Firstly, Peter seems to think that he is using the `fancyvrb` package ("The 
Verbatim (capital V) environment from `fancyvrb` still has that restriction, but has options for a frame and a lot of other bells and whistles."), but as you point out, with the Verbatim env in `fancyvrb` you would have `[frame=single]` not `{frame=single}`. You imply (but do not say) that the latter usage is from `fancybox`. Unfortunately this is not clear from the `fancybox` docs.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "Moreover, the `Verbatim` environment as redefined by `fancybox` seems not to like blank spaces in front of `\end{Verbatim}`". I stuck blank spaces in various places, but it didn't seem to mind. As I mentioned in my answer to Werner, reformatting code gives an error, so there is something wrong here, but not sure what. Also, am even less clear what you mean by "the requirement that `\end{Verbatim`} starts on column 1 is surely a bug". Perhaps you could give an illustrative example? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the illustrative example. I think you meant to put `fancybox` rather than `fancyvrb` in your example, at the current version doesn't really illustrate your point. With `fancyvrb` you get an error with and without a space in front of `\end{Verbatim}`. And I'm not sure about "redefined". Where is `Verbatim` earlier defined, such that `fancybox` is redefining it?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes, it was `fancybox` and not `fancyvrb`

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that both packages define internal commands that are very similar, yet conflicting. For example, [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) defines

```
\def\VerbatimEnvironment{%
  \ifx\FV@EnvironName\relax\xdef\FV@EnvironName{\@currenvir}\fi}
```

while [`fancybox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancybox) defines

```
\def\VerbatimEnvironment{%
  \ifx\@VerbEnvir\relax\xdef\@VerbEnvir{\@currenvir}\fi}
```

Not to say that this is the root of the problem, but it is meant to illustrate the similarities between some of the definitions. As such, switching the load order of the packages could make the one package work, but not the other.

Why does the load order

```
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyvrb}
```

work? Well, because *you* only used functionality provided by `fancyvrb` making the load/use of `fancybox` unnecessary. Why does Peter's suggested solution work? Well, because he didn't need to load `fancyvrb` in the first place, since he only used `fancybox` functionality.

How come you were not alerted of conflicting commands until compilation? That's because many macro definitions and environments are constructed using TeX's `\def` rather than LaTeX's `\newcommand`. The latter automatically checks to see whether a command already exists and issues an error if it does, while the former happily overwrites a previous definition.

Perhaps this could be considered a partial incompatibility between the two packages - an incompatibility none the less.

Comment: Thanks for the summary, Greg. Would best usage be to use `\newcommand` rather than `\def`? And do you think the errors in my example above stem from `fancybox` overwriting something that `fancyvrb` has defined? Actually, Peter's version gives errors too, but (improbably) whether there is an error seems to depend on how it is formatted. I didn't investigate carefully to make sure of this though. I see both   `fancybox` and `fancyvrb` define a `Verbatim` environment. How can you tell Peter is not using `fancyvrb` functionality?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: 1) Many package writers use `\def` which is pure TeX syntax. `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand` and `\providecommand` are from LaTeX and have the built-in checks for existence/not and overwriting. 2) The errors are a combination of the dual loading of conflicting packages, as well as probably an outdated version that you have (since you're running TeX Live 2009, I'm not sure how up-to-date it is; both packages are dated `15/05/2010`). 3) Peter's MWE compiled the same *with* and *without* `fancyvrb`.

Answer (score 0):

The following works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{verbatim}[frame=single]
      auto eth0
    \end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, sorry.

Comment: Is there a Verbatim environment?

Comment: Yes, the `Verbatim` environment is from the `fancyvrb` package.

Comment: OK thanks.  Your code (without including fancybox package) works in TeX Live 2011.  No errors.

Comment: Yes, I know. My question is why including `fancybox` creates problems. If you look at the posting I cite, you'll see this is a stripped down version of code by Peter Flynn.

Comment: OK.  Now I understand the question.

Comment: fancyvrb package extends the functionality of verbatim macros of fancybox package according to the authors of the packages.  That may explain why you have to include fancyvrb package after the fancybox package.

Comment: Possibly, but it seems very brittle. And I suppose my bigger question is, how can one debug this? Perhaps I should rephrase the question to make this clearer.