# fancybox conflict with fancyvrb?

Tags: incompatibility, fancyvrb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error using \usepackage{fancyvrb, fancybox}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39271/error-using-usepackagefancyvrb-fancybox)

I try to implement a simple environment to highlight source code in LaTeX. My solution is :

1. use `VerbatimOut` to write text in a file
2. use `\write18` to execute source-hightlight to handle the saved file
3. `\input` the result in the `\shadowbox`

And it works. The code looks like:

```latex
%%%
%%% A simple environment used to highlight source code
%%% Only usable in linux with source-highlight installed
%%% wwthunan@gmail.com
%%% 2012-07-05 Thu 16:00 PM CST+0800
%%%

\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{fancybox} % must placed before "fancyvrb"
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newcommand{\SourceTabWidth}{4}

\makeatletter
%% USAGE: 
%% \HandleCode{input}{output}{tabwidth}{source language}
\newcommand\HandleCode[4] {
    \immediate\write18{source-highlight --tab=#3 --src-lang=#4 --out-format=latexcolor -i #1 -o #2}
}

%% 
%% USAGE:
%% \begin{SourceCode}{language}
%%      ...code...
%% \end{SourceCode}
%% 
\newenvironment{SourceCode}[1] %
{ %
    \def\mySourceCodeLanguage{#1}
    \def\mySourceCodeInput{\jobname.code.#1}%
    \def\mySourceCodeOutput{\jobname.hcode.tex}%
    \VerbatimEnvironment%
    %% codes option to make sure TAB intact
    \begin{VerbatimOut}[codes={\catcode`\^^I=12}]{\mySourceCodeInput}}%
{\end{VerbatimOut}%
    \HandleCode{\mySourceCodeInput}{\mySourceCodeOutput}{\SourceTabWidth}{\mySourceCodeLanguage} %
    \shadowbox{%
        \parbox{0.8\textwidth}{%
        \input{\mySourceCodeOutput} %
        }%
    }%
    %% delete temp files 
    \immediate\write18{rm \mySourceCodeInput; rm \mySourceCodeOutput}%
}
\makeatother
```

However, there is a problem. When I put `fancyvrb` before `fancybox` package.

```
[codes={\catcode`\^^I=12}]
```

option doesn't work, and a file `[.tex` will be created.

So I guess `fancybox` have changed some internel state. But I can't figure it out.

Any advice will be appreciated!

Save the code to source-highlight.sty. The sample code(sample.tex) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{source-highlight}
\begin{document}
\begin{SourceCode}{cpp}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
\end{SourceCode}
\end{document}
```

And the compile command is:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape sample.tex
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would you please complete your code into something compilable, adding a document class and an example of usage?

Comment: The output seems to be as expected. As explained [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39287/4427) the loading order should always be `fancybox` *before* `fancyvrb`.

Comment: Got it. I found that there are so many restrictions and comflicts among the packages.

Comment: As I explained in the linked answer, `fancybox` wants to define `VerbatimOut` in a different way than `fancyvrb`, so loading the latter after the former ensures that the `fancyvrb` features work. You may want to use `framed` or `mdframed` instead of `fancybox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with current TeXLive 2011 I get the output:

[image]

I used the following code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{source-highlight.sty}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancybox} 
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\SourceTabWidth}{4}
\newcommand\HandleCode[4] {
    \immediate\write18{source-highlight --tab=#3 --src-lang=#4 --out-format=latexcolor -i #1 -o #2}
}
\newenvironment{SourceCode}[1] %
{ \VerbatimEnvironment
    \def\mySourceCodeLanguage{#1}
    \def\mySourceCodeInput{\jobname.code.#1}%
    \def\mySourceCodeOutput{\jobname.hcode.tex}%
    \VerbatimEnvironment%0
\begin{VerbatimOut}[codes={\catcode`\^^I=12}]{\jobname.code.#1}}%
{\end{VerbatimOut}
  \HandleCode{\mySourceCodeInput}{\mySourceCodeOutput}{\SourceTabWidth}{\mySourceCodeLanguage} %
    \shadowbox{%
        \parbox{0.8\textwidth}{%
        \input{\mySourceCodeOutput} %
        }%
    }%
    \immediate\write18{rm \mySourceCodeInput; rm \mySourceCodeOutput}%
}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{source-highlight}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Hihlight demo}
foo
\begin{SourceCode}{cpp}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
\end{SourceCode}
bar
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. The code is too problematic to use. As far as I know, it conflict with beamer because of reload of color package, and the TABs are gone. For xelatex, codes option is redundant.

Comment: for `beamer` use `\PassOptionsToPackage`, see my edited answer. it now uses beamer. My tabs are not gone ...

Comment: Nice, works for both pdfltex and xelatex.